# Using parameters of function in included file

Tags: php, function, include, require

Hey peeps I got a question about this in PHP.

**first_file.php**

```
<?php
    function myFunction($a,$b){
    include 'second.php';
    echo $a;
}

myFunction(5,['Name'=>'Stefan']);
```

---

**second_file.php**

```
<h1><?php echo $b['Name']?></h1>
```

And this code works. So how? I am allowed to use the second parametar $b from the first php file in second php file. Is it because second php file is called from a function?

Thanks nerds! <3

Comment: Think of it as if the content from 'second.php' were copy/pasted to where the `include` line is.  Would you understand how it works then?

Comment: Yes, thanks bro! Can you please post that as answer so other could see better this? :))

Comment: Honestly, a good reading of [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) would answer your question, and include more detail.  I was simplifying it so that you could figure it out yourself.  It's not _exactly_ the same as if it were copy/pasted, especially in this case where you are including some non-PHP content (if copy/paste logic were used, you'd be getting errors).

Comment: Okay, thanks for advice! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer by Patrick Q

---

"Think of it as if the content from 'second.php' were copy/pasted to where the include line is. Would you understand how it works then?"

---